# select a private network interface

Tags: networking

I have this recurring issue where I need to select a network interface that is tied to a private IP network.

That is an address in one of CIDR blocks 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16.

My typical approach to this is this script:

`ip -4 addr show | grep 'inet 10\|192.168'`

This gets the job done, but it seems prone to trouble. Is there a better method? Perhaps a way that I can say only show me ip addresses that talk on the 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16 block?

Comment: Side note: There are *three* blocks of [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt) private address ranges: `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, and `192.168.0.0/16`.  There are also other private-ish ranges.

Comment: I should have included 172.16.0.0/12 as it is the most problematic to grep for.

It seems to mostly be used for things like Docker etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man page says you can use "to PREFIX"

```
ip -4 addr show to 10.0.0.0/8
```

It seems to only obey the last one on the line, so you might have to do it once for each network block.

Comment: Thanks Angelo! I think I misinterpreted that part of the `ip addr help` output.